# vim NERDTreeIgnore for specific files in specific subdirectory

Tags: javascript, vim, nerdtree

i am using https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-local-vimrc for setting project specific vim settings.

now i want to use NERDTreeVimIgnore to ignore javascript files only in the subdirectory src.

i tried that:

```
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['^src*\.js$']
```

but had no success.

```
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.js$']
```

ignores all js files but i need them ignored only in src and its recursive subdirectories.

can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that the `NERDTreeIgnore` option only looks at the last path component (the basename of the file). This means that you won't be able to filter out particular files like that.

The only way I can think of doing this would be by using the `NERDTreeAddPathFilter()` function: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/15445be5fb2559829ac7a1f05af5d713586e8ec9/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L1175

You could create a vim file in your `nerdtree_plugin` directory, for example `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/path_filters.vim`. It would contain something like the example in the docs:

```
call NERDTreeAddPathFilter('MyFilter')

function! MyFilter(params)
  " params is a dict containing keys: 'nerdtree' and 'path' which are
  " g:NERDTree and g:NERDTreePath objects
  " return 1 to ignore params['path'] or 0 otherwise

  " You could do something like this, then:
  let filename = fnamemodify(a:params.path.str(), ':p')
  return filename =~ 'src/myproject/.*\.js'
endfunction
```

You may have to read up a bit in the documentation on writing functions and such, if you run into trouble.